# Connecting to a third party JDBC Connector from Azure Data Factory

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am planning, implementing and running an azure-based reporting architecture for my customer. The source is their ERP systems database, ETL and data storage takes place in an Azure SQL DB, everything in between and the "orchestration" (triggering the right things in the right order at the right time) is mainly handled with ADF.
They are currently running their ERP systems database on an on premise SQL Server, which I connect to from ADF using a Self Hosted Integration Runtime.
Now they want to switch to a SaaS solution their ERP provider offers, which only offers a JDBC connection to query the ERP systems database.

So my question is, is there any possibility to query a JDBC connection directly from ADF?
The basic requirement is getting the data from the ERP database and writing it into staging tables in the Azure SQL DB. However, I would strongly prefer doing it with ADF since the current implementation and all the other ETL stuff is there.

After I've spent some days on Google trying to find possible solutions, I still haven't found much useful information.
The only possible ways I have found are by "misusing" Data Bricks (to read from an JDCB connection and write to Azure SQL DB) or by writing a .NET application and running it as a webjob in Azure.

I'm very thankful for any input that could possibly be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific and let us know about the driver.

From Azure datafctory, you can always call notebook on Adb side ( you neeed to use the note book activity).

Comment: Thank youf or your reply. Unfortunately, I don't really have any further information about the JDBC connection the ERP provider offers. They don't even have a test connection that I can play around with.

I know that I can call Databricks Notebooks from Azure Data Factory, but using Databricks would only be a fallback solution if there is no other way to read data from a JDBC connection and write it into an Azure SQL DB table. Which is all I wanna do, no transformation or anything needed at this point.

Comment: I just found some information about the driver, it seems like it is "Compass JDBC". Do you know if that is supported by Databricks?

Comment: Unfortunately, Compass JDBC is not supported. Here is the list of data sources supported by Azure Databricks:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/

Comment: I am running into the same challenge, exactly with Infor Compass JDBC. No ODBC driver provided. Azure Data Factory does not seem to be an option.

We went with a Databricks notebook approach, with coding in Python, as we are already using Databricks and do some data processing after retrieving the data.

An Azure Function basic example can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGukIBOEAOY